# R package huge - why does taking partial correlation changes the sign of the correlation?

Tags: r, gaussian

I've been using the R package huge to create a gaussian graphical model of log transformed gene expression data (I have 367 genes and 150 samples). However, if I take the correlation of two genes before applying huge I find a positive correlation while when I look at the partial correlation that huge outputs I see a reversal of sign. Aka, if two genes show a positive marginal correlation I see a negative partial correlation when using huge. I understand that the partial correlation should be reducing the correlation but I'm confused as to how it completely changes the sign. Does anyone know why this might be or would be able to point me to a different package?

```
library(huge)

#The TCGA Pancreatic Illumina sequencing with patients as columns
#and genes as rows
rnaseq.read = as.matrix(read.table("PAAD_HiSeqV2.gz", header = T, row.names = 1, sep="\t"))

#This gives a list of the 360 genes we're interested in
genes_list = read.table("DE_gene_high_v_low.txt",header=T,sep="\t")

rnaseq = rnaseq.read[(rownames(rnaseq.read) %in% gene_list),]

#An example being RARG which has been shown to bind to a KCNN4 promoter
#likely leading to increase in KCNN4
#When I plot this I see a positive slope as expected
plot(rnaseq[,"RARG"],rnaseq[,"KCNN4"])

PDAC.all = huge(t(rnaseq), method="glasso")
PDAC.all.select = huge.select(PDAC.all, criterion="stars")
PDAC_icov = as.matrix(PDAC.all.select$opt.icov)
ig_PDAC = graph.adjacency(PDAC_icov, mode="undirected", weighted=TRUE, add.colnames = "name")

#However, when I look at the partial correlation matrix, the correlation is now -0.201
PDAC_icov["RARG","KCNN4"]
```

I would expect the partial correlation to still be positive but it's negative. I see this with other pairings as well where those with positive marginal correlations have negative partial correlations and vice versa.

Comment: The partial correlation can be larger than the marginal correlation. It can be the opposite sign. That is something that can (and clearly does) happen.

Comment: Hi @Dason, I understand that but over 90% change signs. In addition, I ran a separate program this morning (GeneNet) that estimates shrinkage instead of using a lasso and the signs remain the same. We still get approximately the same list of partial correlations but only 13% of edges match to the huge estimate of positive or negative. I'm wondering if anyone knows something about huge that may explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"glasso"` method returns the precision matrix in the variable `opt.icov`. To get the partial correlation estimate, you need to convert the precision into a correlation matrix and change its sign (see Wikipedia page for more details).

In your case, `PDAC.all.select$opt.icov` represent the inverse covariance (precision) matrix.
To get the partial correlation, you need to change its sign and divide by the product of the square root of the diagonal elements:

`partial.corr = -cov2cor(PDAC.all.select$opt.icov)`